# Knockout 'attr' data bindings with function throws error when using a custom binding provider

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

We have 60-70 cshtml pages in our ASP.NET MVC Project with a lot of knockout implementations in it.

We decided to add CSP to our current application to prevent it from unsafe inline scripts and eval() functions. So i added CSP policies to my MVC App builder and then provided nonce to allow my inline scripts. To make Knockout CSP complaint , i had to use a custom binding provider (https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding) . After which few of my knockout bindings started working fine and i stopped seeing the **'CSP policy violation'** errors in the browser console.

But even then a lot of them are still not working (i get 2 uncaught errors on console but more than 2 binding fail) each of which have **'attr'** knockout binding.

I was not able to find any relevant sources on web to resolve these errors and since they are knockout internal script related , i am not able to make head or tail of it.

I've been trying to fix the bindings on the first dashboard page before going ahead.

Custom Binding provider:

```
var options = {
               attribute: "data-bind",        
               globals: window,               
               bindings: ko.bindingHandlers,  
               noVirtualElements: false       
            };
            ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.secureBindingsProvider(options); enter code here
```

HTML Block for one of the binding (Entire HTML is too long) (_Layout.cshtml):

```
    <!-- Banner -->
    <div id="bannerCarousel" class="bannerContainer">
        <div id="topCarousel" class="topBannerSlider carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
            <ol tabindex="0" id="bannercarousel-indicators" class="carousel-indicators" role="tablist" data-bind="foreach: { data: carouselBanners, as: 'carouselBanner' }">
                <li class="active" data-target="#topCarousel" data-bind="attr: { 'data-slide-to': $index(),'title':'Slide '+($index()+1),'id': 'bannertab-0-' + $index(), 'aria-controls': 'bannertabpanel-0-' + $index(),'aria-label':'Slider '+($index()+1)+'tab, To activate tab page press Enter.' }">
                    <span class="sr-only" data-bind="text: carouselBanner.Title+' '+carouselBanner.Tagline+' '+carouselBanner.Description"></span>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <ul class="bannerslider carousel-inner" data-bind="foreach: { data: carouselBanners, as: 'carouselBanner' }, topCarouselActive">
                <li class="item active" role="tabpanel" data-bind="attr: {'id': 'bannerslidertabpanel-0-' + $index(), 'aria-labelledby':'bannerslidertab-0-' + $index()}">
                    <div data-bind="attr: { class: $root.currentClass(carouselBanner.BannerClass) }">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="bannerContent">
                                    <h1 class="bannerTitle" data-bind="text: carouselBanner.Title"></h1>
                                    <h2 class="bannerTagline" data-bind="text: carouselBanner.Tagline"></h2>
                                    <p class="bannerDesc" data-bind="text: carouselBanner.Description"></p>
                                    <!--button class="bannerBtnReadMore btn">Read More</button-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="bannerImage bannerImage1" data-bind="if: (carouselBanner.LogoUrl != '' && carouselBanner.LogoUrl != null && carouselBanner.LogoUrl != 'undefined') ">
                                    <img data-bind="attr:{src: carouselBanner.LogoUrl}" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a role="button" href="javascript:void(0)#topCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" title="Previous Slide">
                <i class="ose-fo ose-icon-arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a role="button" href="javascript:void(0)#topCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" title="Next Slide">
                <i class="ose-fo ose-icon-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Banner -->
```

The Javascript file (viewmodel.carousel.js):

```
function Carousel() {
EstimatorApp.AccessService.getCarouselDetail(null, function (data) {       
    if (data.IsSuccess) {
        if (data.Result) {                
            var viewModel = {
                carouselBanners: ko.observableArray(data.Result),
                currentClass: function (bannerClass) {
                    return "globalBanner bannerBgImg " + bannerClass;
                },
            };

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("bannerCarousel"));
        }
    }
});
}
```

**The Carousel function is called in _Layout.cshtml.**

The errors in the browser console:

[image]

In message expanded view:

1st Error:
[image]

2nd Error:
[image]

**Both the bindings fails at this line (2824):**

[image]

I do not have much idea of the internal working of knockout so if anyone can help i would really appreciate it.
Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but it seems these errors complain because you pass a function *definition* to `foreach` and `if` bindings. You can turn these into IIFT - [see a demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/1v3tzaub/) - though this is quite an unusual usage, but maybe it'd solve it.

Comment: Thanks @HeyJude , for the timebeing , we stopped CSP from blocking eval methods and focus on inline scripts as this library is not stable. But i will surely check out your recommendation and see if i can accomodate it in our application.